# Considering empty string to null in query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using `sql server R2`. I have a stored procedure in which I am passing two paramaters as `@username varchar(100)` and `@password varchar(100)`.

Now,  when I create user from my application first time, the password will be NULL.

I want to make a query which return record for matching username and password. The problem is code is passing `empty string` to `stored procedure`. I want something that consider or convert `empty string to NULL` automatically. I already have solution for this using `if condition` but I want to use single query, not if condition.

**EDIT :**

Its a simple stored procedure :

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_TblP]
(
 @userName varchar(100),
 @password varchar(100) 
)
AS
BEGIN
    IF (@password ='')
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM TblP 
            WHERE username = @userName AND password IS NULL AND IsDeleted = 0
        END

    ELSE 
        BEGIN
            SELECT * FROM TblP 
            WHERE username = @userName AND password = @password AND IsDeleted = 0
    END
END

GO
```

I want to combine the query in single representation. Don't want the if condition.

Comment: We can help if you show us your code. What does it look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_TblP]
(
 @userName varchar(100),
 @password varchar(100) 
)
AS
BEGIN
   SELECT * FROM TblP 
   WHERE username = @userName AND COALESCE(password,'') = @password AND IsDeleted = 0

END

GO
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e8007/2)

Comment: @Dev : Check Fiddle and tell me where are you facing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code :
 when @password  is empty string OR null it will return all values. when you pass a string in @password  variable it will then filter it.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_TblP]
(
 @userName varchar(100),
 @password varchar(100) 
)
AS
BEGIN
     SELECT * FROM TblP 
         WHERE username = @userName AND IsDeleted = 0
         And (password = @password OR  isnull(@password,'') = '')           

END
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
alter PROCEDURE [dbo].[Pro_TblP]
(
 @userName varchar(100),
 @password varchar(100)='' 
)
AS
BEGIN
   BEGIN
      SELECT * FROM TblP 
      WHERE username = @userName AND IsNull(password,'')=@password AND IsDeleted = 0
   END
END
```

Comment: Where are you comparing password with parameter @password in above stored procedure you have given?

Comment: @Dev: Updated it, was a typo when copy from my query analyser

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM TblP 
WHERE username = @userName AND 
      IsDeleted = 0 AND
      (
        password = @password OR
        password IS NULL AND @password = ''
      )
```